# Cómo llamar a una tabla de otro var en LINQ

Tags: linq

He creado 2 sentencias linq.

Ejemplo:

```
 var busqueda1 = (from c in Cliente
                  bla bla bla
                  select{
                  });
 var busqueda2 = (from p in Proveedor
                 ble ble ble
                 select{
                 });
```

Lo que me gustaría es que en la *busqueda2* pudiera llamar a alguna tabla de *busqueda1*.
¿Hay alguna posibilidad?

Answer (score 0):

Hola @Jordi P puedes realizar un inner join si las dos tablas tiene alguna foreginkey, que espero que si.

```
(from d in Tabla1 join w in Tabla2 on d.IdTabla1 equals w.IdTabla2
where bla bla bla
select new {
    Propiedad1 = d.Propiedad,
    Propiedad2 = w.Propiedad,
    etc...
}
```

Aquí estas realizando un inner join con las dos tablas y después devuelves un objeto con propiedades que quieras de las dos tablas ha la vez espero que sea lo que estas buscando.

Comment: Gracias Jordi! Al final he podido solucionar mi error de principiante (llevo menos de un mes trabajando de esto). 

Realizamos un Union de 2 tablas pero mi error era que estaba intentando llamarla por el nombre de la var o no sabia entrar dentro de las tablas. 

Finalmente me he dado cuentas que cuando creaba un nuevo var a partir de la union anterior, var unionActual = (from un in unionAnterior ), lo que debía hacer para entrar dentro era hacerlo desde un. y no desde unionAnterior.

Novatada pero aprendido. 
Gracias de nuevo por tu respuesta